# How to change scheduler date format in *_node_form

Tags: nodes, datetime

When I go to fill a *_node_form I find that Scheduler module only have this date format "Y m d" "H:m:s" and I would like to have "d m Y" "H:m:s".

I'm looking to the module and I don't find anyway, also , I have make a dpm with $form, And I don't find anyplace to change the date format.

Can be done this?

Thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 0):

I find it the url is: admin/config/content/scheduler

The strange is that it doesn't have a "configuration" link in module page list.

Oskar